# Cropping an image into Hexagon shape in a web page

Tags: php, css, image

I have an image in a web page. I want to convert the four-sided image into a six-sided one. i.e. Crop the edges and convert the image into an hexagon shape.

How can I do it using PHP ImageMagick/GD on my server side. I am using XAMPP server to build a sample web page. Or is there a better way to do it using Javascript/CSS by making use of img style attributes.

Comment: What can you use on server-side, ImageMagick? GD?

Comment: You are presumably aware that you can't have an image that is *actually* six-sided? Unless it is a vector graphic, that the browser would need a plugin to display, and PHP would *not* be the language for creating...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It'll be less painful in CSS (you don't even need JS on this).

see this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/bhGn4/

Comment: Now that is some neat CSS that deserves a *big* +1. I presume you had that stashed somewhere? If you wrote it all that quickly I am *very* impressed...

Comment: Yeah I never said it was mine. I had it bookmarked since last september ;)

Answer (score 3):

Since I needed to use multiple sizes and caching I needed it in php (well, server-side:)) :

```
// doge.jpg is a squared pic
$raw = imagecreatefromjpeg('doge.jpg'); 

/* Simple math here

  A_____F
  /     \
B/       \E
 \       /
 C\_____/D

*/
$w = imagesx($raw); 
$points = array(
    .25 * $w, .067  * $w, // A 
    0, .5   * $w, // B
    .25 * $w, .933  * $w, // C
    .75 * $w, .933  * $w, // D
    $w, .5  * $w, // E
    .75 * $w, .067  * $w  // F
);

// Create the mask
$mask = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $w);
imagefilledpolygon($mask, $points, 6, imagecolorallocate($mask, 255, 0, 0));

// Create the new image with a transparent bg
$image = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $w);
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagealphablending($image, false);
imagesavealpha($image, true);
imagefill($image, 0, 0, $transparent);

// Iterate over the mask's pixels, only copy them when its red.
// Note that you could have semi-transparent colors by simply using the mask's 
// red channel as the original color's alpha.
for($x = 0; $x < $w; $x++) {
    for ($y=0; $y < $w; $y++) { 
        $m = imagecolorsforindex($mask, imagecolorat($mask, $x, $y));
        if($m['red']) {
            $color = imagecolorsforindex($raw, imagecolorat($raw, $x, $y));
            imagesetpixel($image, $x, $y, imagecolorallocatealpha($image,
                              $color['red'], $color['green'], 
                              $color['blue'], $color['alpha']));
        }
    }
}

// Display the result
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

You should get something similar to this:

[image: wow, much hexagonal]

Comment: do you have any idea on how to do this in laravel ? also  can we rotate the hexagon 90 deg ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use HTML5 canvas to mask the edges and then read out the image using a Data URI.

Also be aware that for this technique to work, you'll have to proxy the image to your domain, since Canvas marks its contents dirty if an image is loaded from a foreign domain.

**UPDATE:** I've added a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XnzP8/1/) that demonstrates this technique.

Comment: @Krof Drakula: I unable to find anything in the jsfiddle. Am I missing something.?

Comment: Forgot to click 'Update', it's fixed now.